# UIView won't move to a new position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm having a little trouble here moving a UIView up.  Here are my codes.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
if ([self.expenseToShowDetail.recurring intValue] == 1) {

//something...

} else {

    [self.recurringView setHidden:YES];

    self.noteUIView.layer.position = CGPointMake(160, 200);

}
}
```

I'm trying to hide 1 view and move the other up a bit.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a nib or a storyboard, or are you creating your views in code?

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
self.noteUIView.center = CGPointMake(160, 200);
```

You were accessing `self.noteUIView`'s layer property, which may not have been what you were looking to do. Also, this code will not visibly move the view, it will just put it a 160, 200.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working is because you've added it to viewWillAppear: method.

Add the following line to viewDidLayoutSubviews or viewDidAppear:

```
[self.noteUIView setCenter:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
```

Answer (score 1):

View will not move once the frame is changed. we need to animate the view to move to new position. try the below code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{     
    CGRect rect = self.noteUIView.frame;
    rect.origin.x = 160;
    rect.origin.y = 200;
    self.noteUIView.frame = rect;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
[self.noteUIView setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 200)];
```

or

```
 self.noteUIView.frame=self.noteUIView.frame=CGRectMake(160, 200, self.noteUIView.frame.origin.size.width, self.noteUIView.frame.origin.size.height);
```